# Close menu on click event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've used the following code to create a hamburger style menu that slides in from the left and covers the whole screen. Some of my menu links are regular links to other pages and others are anchor links to further down the homepage. But, when the anchor links are clicked, you can see the scrollbar has gone done to that section but the menu doesn't close.

What do I need to add to the script (I assume it's the script) to make this happen?

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="/home/">Home</a>
    <a href="/#services/">Services</a>
    <a href="/clients/">Clients</a>
    <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <h2>Animated Sidenav Example Full Width</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the navigation menu.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't know if it works for you but when you `href` to `/#services/` it doesn't work, so I recommend you to drop the `/` and just `href="#services"`.

Next thing you want to do is to add `onclick` on that specific anchor to close the nav bar:

```js
<a href="#services" onclick="closeNav()">Services</a>
```

And the full result:

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="/home/">Home</a>
    <a href="#services" onclick="closeNav()">Services</a>
    <a href="/clients/">Clients</a>
    <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <h2>Animated Sidenav Example Full Width</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the navigation menu.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
  
  
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  
  <div id="services">HI THIS IS SERVICES</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar default state better be `display:none` and had a sibling class like `.show`, then all you need is just to toggle the `.show` class with Javascript.

Changing `display` is the basic CSS property you can use, you also can use `position:absolute` with position properties like `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` with transition.

```html
<div class="sidenav">
 <button class="closebtn">
  Close sidebar
 </button>
 ...
</div>
```

```css
.sidenav {
 ...
 display: none;
}

.sidenav.show {
 display: block;
}
```

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
const closebtn = document.querySelector('.closebtn');

closebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 sidebar.classList.toggle('show');
});
```